# How to iterate using Iterator

Tags: java

I am using Iterator on Arraylist. I was trying to run this program but it is throwing ConcurrentModification exception.

```
Iterator<ATableRow> itrAAList = dataList.iterator();
Iterator<? extends ATableRow> itrVIPAAList = fActivityList.iterator();

while(itrVIPAAList.hasNext()){
    ATableRow aTableRow = itrVIPAAList.next();

    while(itrAAList.hasNext()){
        ATableRow row = itrAAList.next();
        if(!row.getAId().equals(aTableRow.getAId())){
            dataList.add(aTableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dataList.add`. Oops!

Comment: @Boris, How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Don't modify any `Collection` during iteration. Ever. Except through the `Iterator`.

Comment: But here my requirement is to add into dataList. Can I do it by some other way.

Comment: **Except through the `Iterator`**. Anything unclear here?

Answer (score -2):

please convert your list to ConcurrentHashMap();